# What happens to the portions of large glued displays that aren't retasked into a different display?

Tags: history, glue

When LEGOLAND dismantles a glued display, is it recycled into something other than LEGO, or do they have to be thrown away?  I know certain portions of a display might be utilized again in a different display, like some cars and trailers from the now defunct Speedway at LEGOLAND California were, but what happens to the rest of the model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases they would be reused in other parks, donated to LEGO retail stores, auctioned for charity or hidden away from park visitors. As a last resort, LEGO models can and will be recycled to create new bricks.

The LEGO auction site, Bricklink has a fairly hidden place to trade [glued models](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemType=G&catID=683&itemStatus=U) and [retail displays](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemType=G&catID=539&itemStatus=U).

Comment: Thanks Ambo100- I started researching to see what I could find. I always thought that by glueing LEGO elements it tainted them and  prevented recycling them and they had to go to a landfill. I'm happy to see that isn't true. It turns out that the best ABS bonding agent is Acetone or an ABS based glue that can bond the parts together without corupting the ABS plastic which allows fused LEGO models to become new LEGO elements. Awesome.

Comment: Here is a point of reference- http://www.mp3car.com/fabrication/93247-best-adhesive-for-bonding-abs-to-abs.html